# What Brand faucet is this?

Tags: bathtub

I have to replace the hot stem but cannot determine the brand/model of this triple bath tub faucet.  It was installed about 1992/1993.[image]

Comment: Do you have the old one?

Comment: Removing the stem, with the water off, and taking it to local plumbing shop/store(not big box) should help.